# Preg_match on auth_user

Tags: php

```php
class User
{
    public $username;

    public function __construct()
    {
        //echo 'Blank for now';
    }

    public function register() {
        echo $this->username . ' has been registered.';
    }

    public function login($username, $password) {
        $this->auth_login($username, $password);
    }

    public function auth_login($username, $password) {
        if (preg_match('/[a-zA-Z]/', $username)) {
            echo $username . ' has been authenticated.';
        } else {
            echo 'Please input a username with letters only.';
        }
    }
}

$user = new User();

$user->login('Semir%', 'Zxcvbnm');
```

Am I doing something wrong with preg_match? I want to be able to accept only 'letters' as the $username but it seems like 'Semir%' returns also: `Semir% has been authenticated.`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your regular expression would match any string that contains at least 1 letter.

The expression you are looking for is `/^[a-zA-Z]+$/`.

- ^ matches the start of string
- [a-zA-Z] matches any letter
- + says that previous part of expresion ([a-zA-Z]) must be pressent at least once but may  repeat
- $ matches the end of string

Answer (score 0):

the [a-zA-Z] returns true for Semir% because [a-zA-Z] is the range of letters from a to z small caps and big caps. there is a tool for checking your regular expressions: https://regex101.com/